# internet connection problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dns

I was trying to fix my internet connection problem in Ubuntu 20.04. My firefox is not working. The error I got after running Sudo apt-get update.

- Err:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease Temporary
  failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' Err:2
  http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease Temporary
  failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' Err:3
  http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' Err:4
  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease Temporary
  failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com' Reading package lists... Done
  W: Failed to fetch
  http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease Temporary
  failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' W: Failed to fetch
  http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' W: Failed to
  fetch
  http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' W: Failed to
  fetch
  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com' W: Some index files
  failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I found a few posts regarding this problem in the forum. I tried to use: sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf. But it didn't work, and said bash: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory. Obviously, there's an empty folded named /etc/resolv.conf. I ended up with adding #nameserver 8.8.8.8 in resolv.conf.save, But I can't have it saved under resolv.conf. These are the files I got under /etc. Many thanks

- resolv.conf
  resolv.conf.save
  resolv.conf.save.1

Comment: Very clear what is wrong. The error message is telling you that that mirror is down at least for now change to a different mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to delete resolv.conf whether it's a file or a directory. If you think it's a folder as you mentioned in the post, try `sudo rm -rf resolv.conf`. If it's a symlink file, execute `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conv`. Then edit the file you just created with `sudo echo 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf`. That should solve your problem.